# UINavigationController with TTNavigator

Tags: cocoa-touch, ttnavigator

I am using a UINavigationController in the appdelegate as a basis for all views and I am using the TTNavgitor for antother flow starting with a TTTableViewController.

When I use the TTNavigator for some reason I have 2 problems:

1. After I choose one of the rows there is no back button in the viewcontroller loaded
2. The transition is not animated when selecting a row in the table

I am using the basis of the Three20 examples:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        self.title = @"Settings";
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
        [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                         target:nil action:nil] autorelease];


        self.tableViewStyle = UITableViewStyleGrouped;



        TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
        navigator.supportsShakeToReload = YES;
        navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeNone;
        navigator.window = self.view.window;





        TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
        [map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];
        [map from:@"tt://login" toViewController:[LoginController class]];


    }
    return self;
}
```

Does some has an idea why do I have these problems? and how can I solve this fast without rewriting all of the code?